# How to implement a REST API HTTP PUT method to update a record in MongoDB with AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afhttpclient, afhttprequestoperation

I created a full RESTful API using `node.js` and `mongoDB`. Using `AFNetworking`, I could easily implement `GET` to retrieve a list of products via the API but I'm having trouble doing a `PUT` method to update a record. The idea is check if there is a record for this UUIDString, if there is update the record.

If I run a cURL command in terminal. This will work:

```
Modify with _id value of 6FDCBF3D:

curl -i -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name": "someName", "someValue": "15"}' http://localhost:3000/iaps/6FDCBF3D/
```

Objective-c Code:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/iaps/"];
           // NSString *uuid = [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString;
            AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
            [client getPath:@"6FDCBF3D" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                NSError *jsonError = nil;
                NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
//                NSLog(@"Return object: %@", json);
                if (json) {
                    NSString *purchasedPkg = [productIdentifier pathExtension];
                    if ([purchasedPkg isEqualToString:@"productA"]) {
                        NSString *oldPkg = [json objectForKey:@"somevalue"];
                        int newPkgVal = oldPkg.intValue + 1;
                        NSString *newPkg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newPkgVal];
                        [json setValue:newPkg forKey:@"somevalue"];
                    }

                    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"PUT" path:@"6FDCBF3D" parameters:nil];
                    request.HTTPBody = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:json options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];
                    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [client HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                        NSLog(@"put success");
                    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                        NSLog(@"put failed");
                    }];
                }
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }];
```

Comment: Just a hint: at a minimum you should check the HTTP status code which determines whether your request actually succeeded. Also check if you actually received a JSON. Otherwise, if anything goes wrong you might receive a JSON containing an error description or no JSON at all - say in case of a server error it may return text/html. If this happens your method fails silently or fails somewhere else. Use Unit tests to confirm your client API works even in failure cases.

Answer (score 0):

`AFNetworking` provides `put` method as follows:

```
- (void)putPath:(NSString *)path 
     parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters 
        success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
        failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
```